# Custom HTML for a form widget

Tags: theming, forms, 9

How can I change a node edit form so that boolean fields use a toggle switch instead of a checkbox? Currently they look like this

[image]

and I would like to update them to be more intuitive like this (https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/YzEdrKj)

[image]

I think what I need to do is implement a custom widget as described here (https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-field-widget) but there really aren't any good docs or guides on this.

The example given there just uses a regular text field, how do I alter the HTML & CSS markup to be a toggle switch?

Answer (score 2):

The doc you've linked shows that you need to define a render array for you element. You can attach an asset to it using `['#attached']` array key. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml#s-attaching-a-library-to-a-form.

Comment: That's for attaching a CSS or JS file though, right? I want to change the actual HTML markup used and doing it with JS seems kinda janky

Comment: You probably won’t want to change the markup - it needs to stay as an input for accessibility. Using JS to enhance form elements is standard practice